# Is dream interpretation haram in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, dream

In my very possibly mistaken belief, there is a thin line between religion and superstition that we should not cross.

> I want to know whether the activity of dream interpretation is haram according to Quran and sahih al-hadith.

There are many ways to do dream interpretation, in particular I'm talking about the type that [this website](http://www.myislamicdream.com/) provides, for example [like this entry about horse](http://www.myislamicdream.com/search.html?txtSearch=horse&cmdSearch=Search).

It cites people's words about the dreams. But people must not make things up, what is their basis to talk about all these dreams? Only what God revealed through Quran and through Muhammad (PBUH) can be a reference, all the rest can only be hearsay, which is a sin. Does that mean such activities should be haram?

Comment: Also see http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/817/can-we-seek-interpretation-of-dreams

Comment: Dream interpretation was very popular during the Abbasid Caliphate (and possibly others) and there were quite a few syaikhs who spent their whole lives specializing in it. Then again, just because a lot of Muslims did it, doesn't make it halal or non-superstition.

Comment: You should read more about ibn sirin :)
www.myislamicdream.com/ibn_sireen_book.html‎

do you wanna read it ? here it is www.kister.huji.ac.il/sites/default/files/dreams.pdf‎

Answer (score 3):

No dream interpretation is not haram, and those who interpret dreams may get it right or may get it wrong as is clear from what the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) [said](http://sunnah.com/urn/361021) to Abu Bakr when he interpreted a dream:

> أَصَبْتَ بَعْضًا وَأَخْطَأْتَ بَعْضًا
>
> You have interpreted a part of it correctly and you have erred in
> interpreting a part of it

Also, it is known that Allah blessed Prophet Yusuf (peace be upon him) with the ability to interpret dreams, as well as people came to the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) and he used to interpret them, as well as others like Abu Bakr.

Also, it must be understood that not all dreams should be told, for instance if one has a dream that comes from Shaytaan, one that he dislikes, or in other words if he has a bad dream or nighmare then he should not tell it to anyone and should keep it to himself.  For dreams are of three types, one from Shaytaan, and one that is from Allah.

If you see a dream that you like, then you may tell to those whom you love or trust, but not those whom you fear harm from.  Like how Yusuf (peace be upon him) told his father about his dream, and his father advised him not to tell his brothers.  You may also seek interpretation from scholars and those who give advice.

So in the end, no dream interpretation is not haram and is ok.

For more information see [this (In Arabic)](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/183857).

Comment: “No dream interpretation is not haram” would logically mean that every dream interpretation is haram.

Answer (score -1):

No its not haram. But make sure you go to the right person who has knowledge about dream interpretation and has knowledge about Islam.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. I recommend you to consider elaborating your ansewr to make it more helpful see [answer].