# Is there any evidence in Islam that demonstrates how a person should interpret dreams?

Tags: dream

Is there any evidence in Islam that demonstrates how a person should interpret dreams? We know for example that Yusuf (peace be upon him) and Abu Bakr (may Allah be satisfied with him) were excellent in interpreting dreams. How does a person get to interpret dreams? Is it a science that can be learned or a strict guidance from Allah?

Comment: This is relevant if not even answering the question [How does dream interpretation distinguish itself from fortune telling?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36379/how-does-dream-interpretation-distinguish-itself-from-fortune-telling).

Comment: So you agree that's it's "speculative business" and has as many interpretations as there are interpreters? Therefore not a science that can be pinpointed or studied?

Comment: Dream interpretation is something really hard to learn. You must have full knowledge of Quran and Sunnah if you want to interpret dreams.

Comment: @Shadi how do you come this conclusion?

Comment: @Medi the post you referred to me states so?

Comment: Nope it asks about that only. From the perspective of Islam dream interpretation is a science as my answer says.

Comment: I agree with Medi. It is a science and can be learnt.

Comment: Great. What sources do you guys recommend to study dream interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

I used to think that dreams can be shared with only your well-wishers, but after reading this following hadith I changed my mind. So it should not be shared regardless. We can see that from the hadith mentioned both in Bukhari and Muslim.

It was narrated from Jaabir that a Bedouin came to the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and said,

> “I dreamt that my head was cut off and I was chasing it.” The
>   Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)
>   rebuked him and said: “**Do not tell anyone how the Shaytaan is
>   messing about with you in your dreams**.”

(Narrated by Muslim, 2268)

It was a bad dream and Prophet (pbuh) definitely was a well-wisher, yet still he said

> Do not tell anyone

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) told us the difference between good dreams and bad dreams. It was narrated from Abu Sa’eed al-Khudri that he heard the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say:

> “If any one of you sees a dream that he likes, it is from Allaah, so
>   let him praise Allaah for it and tell people about it. But if he sees
>   something other than that, that he dislikes, it is from the Shaytaan,
>   so let him seek refuge with Allaah from its evil and **not mention it
>   to anyone**, for it will not harm him.”

(Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 7045).

So it is clear that good dreams come from Allaah and bad dreams which a person dislikes come from the Shaytaan, so he has to seek refuge with Allaah from their evil.

Answer (score 0):

Many dreams are very important so you cannot take dreams lightly. Of course you may see some misleading dreams too. To my understanding dreams are a hint on what can happen in future. As dream is mostly hint, it will not happen exactly but the hint about future is crucial for you in many cases.

Comment: You mean like a Ilham (Premonition)