# How do Muslims interpret dreams?

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, hadith-interpretation, dream

I do  know the Hadith about the three type of dreams but I'm trying to figure out is there a sahih source that Muslims may refer to understand one's dream?

I read that Prophets were able to do that (as shown in Hadith about Yousuf & Mohammed (PBUT)). But what about others?

Comment: This seems relevant https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36379/how-does-dream-interpretation-distinguish-itself-from-fortune-telling

Comment: The last questions seems not to be about dream-Interpretation you should ask it separately.

Comment: I still think this question should be closed as too broad! I count four different questions.

Comment: Your change is covered in the answers of the linked post! So this seems to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "How do Muslims interpret dreams?"

Dream interpretation is an ability bestowed by Allah (ﷻ) and without that ability, we have no means or methods to interpret dreams. There is also no resource that you can go to that will give you an interpretation to every dream. (Each dream is unique per person).

If interested you may read this compilation I made: [Meanings of Dreams from the Sunnah](https://veiledink.wordpress.com/2017/05/16/meanings-of-dreams-from-the-sunnah/). It has examples of dreams the Prophet or Sahabah had and their meanings as interpreted by the Prophet (ﷺ). All from authentic sources.